# Android studio doesn't recognize flutter class AppBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I fix it `const` issue on appBar ?

[image]

Comment: try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` in your terminal (inside of the root project).

Comment: Don't upload screenshots of your code, try to copy/paste it into your questions. Concerning your question, Adison answer should solve your problem.

Comment: use const keyword before your AppBar widget

Answer (score 3):

While you are adding `title:Text(..)` `AppBar` is not `const` anymore. Therefore, the parent `MaterialApp` cant be `const`.

You can do

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("this is te"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code will have diagnostic-messages on error:
[const_with_non_const](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=const_with_non_const#const_with_non_const)

```
// correct 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(),
    ),
  );
}
```

```
// fail
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

While `Text('AppBar Demo')` is a const, it is preferred to add const before it.

```
// not preferred
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar Demo'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

```
// preferred
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('AppBar Demo'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't show errors now but when i clicked in dart analysis i found this error info: Unused import: 'package:iam_rich/main.dart'. (unused_import at [iam_rich] test\widget_test.dart:11)

Comment: Also the app isn't working in the emulator

Comment: You might post another question related to iam_rich. I cannot find any clues to answer you. When widget test is not usable in you own case, delete the whole test folder first.

Comment: Unused imports do not mean errors. Simply delete all those lines or just neglect them.